# Windows 2003 Server IIS App. Can only access with the IP address in the URL

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003, http-status-code-401

I have a problem with an Web App implemented in Windows 2003 Server IIS.

My machine is not in the domain.

If I put the IP address, for example

```
**http://192.168.1.210:5555/App**
```

I'm asked for my domain credentials DOMAIN\USER1 and I login correctyly.

However, if I put the server name,

```
http://WEBSERVER:5555/App, I get:
```

HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied -> with Internet Explorer 7, altough I'm asked for the credentials.

Error 338 (net::ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS) -> With Chrome directly, no credentials asked.

Any settings in IIS I should check?

Thanks!

Comment: if you ping WEBSERVER, does it reslove to the right ip 192.168.1.210?

Comment: Yes, the name resolution works. Actually I can access other Web Apps in this server, for example http://WEBSERVER:8080/App

Comment: Can you check 1) Select Website -> Authentication -> Windows Authentication -> Advanced Settings -> See if Kernal Mode Authentication is enabled. 2) Compare the Application Pool accounts you are running the websites.

Comment: No luck yet, I have tried different combinations of authentications, Windows, text, basic. Also from the command line, I've changed the option from 'Kerberos,NTML' to only 'NTML' but no luck. I've tried different pool accounts, using the same as other apps and different. The real anoying thing is I can login with the IP, and DNS is working perfectly.